# How do I pass total from the function Score() to the function ScoreResult(), it says misssing 1 positional argument

Tags: python

How do I pass the argument total down to the function ScoreResult, I have been wondering what is the problem with my code

```
def InputData():
    name = input("Enter a name: ")
    score = int(input(("Enter a score: ")))
    return name, score

def Score():
    total = 0 
    name, score = InputData()
    if score <= 100:
        total += 10
    if score <=20:
        total += 2

    return total 


def ScoreResult(total):
    score_result = ""
    name, score = InputData()
    print(score_result + f"{name} : {total}")

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    ScoreResult(total)
```

Comment: You defined `ScoreResult` as a function that takes one parameter but you pass 0 parameter when you do `if __name__ == "__main__" :  ScoreResult()`

Comment: I have added ScoreResult(total) but it still doesn't work

Comment: Do you really need the `total` variable ? It still does not work because `total` is never defined. But do you need to have total ? You never use it anywhere